# MPI code using more CPU resources than allocated (over-committing)

Tags: multithreading, mpi, cpu-usage, hpc, slowdown

Here is the situation:
I'm running a genetic algorithm (GA) optimization code that calls a standalone package (ccx) to do the function evaluation. To improve the efficiency, the GA code is paralleled using MPI. The program is allocated, say, N+1 cores on a HPC cluster. Then it will use the N cores to call the standalone evaluation package in parallel, wait for them to finish, assess the results, then generate a new set of parameters to start a new round of evaluations. This process is repeated until a certain criteria is met.

Here's the problem:
The program **sometimes** over-commits the allocated resources. 
The following is an example output of the `top` command sent to me by the administrator of the cluster. Note that the CPU usage is 200%.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 7498 bgeng     20   0  148512  17912   5300 R 199.3  0.0 534:31.08 GATOOL
```

The admin tells me that my code is doing threading somewhere. Since hyper-threading is disabled on the cluster (i.e. 1 core 1 process), it is running two processes on 1 core and slows down the entire computing node.

I don't think the threading is happening in the standalone package, because the over-committing does not happen when I run it alone with 1 core. Besides, the over-committing seems to occur in only one process among all the MPI processes allocated.
**What could be the places or conditions where the over-committing can happen?** I know little about MPI and I'm more of a user than a developer of the program. But I can try to test some clues. My apology if the question is too abstract ...

The admin asked me to add

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
```

in the job submission script, which I tried and not helping.

This is pseudo code showing the structure of the program

```
main()
{
  MPI_INIT()
  while(criteria not met){
   if(myid>0) execute_command_line('./ccx',wait=.ture.)
   if(myid==0) assess results
  }
  MPI_Finalize()
}
```

Comment: Is `GATOOL` the MPI app ? Can you run `pstack <pid>` when it is using 200% resources ? Does your MPI app fork&exec an external binary ? If so, how do you do this ?

Comment: Yes, `GATOOL` is the MPI app. It executes an standalone package using the system call `execute_command_line`. I'll test the `pstack` when I can. Thank you!